# If I get Ubuntu, can I still have Windows 7 on my HP Pavilion i5 DV6 Laptop?

Tags: windows

Like can I easily switch between Windows 7 and Ubuntu easily without any risk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wubi to install it or to make dual boot menu . Go to >>>  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: are you sure Wubi can be used to dual boot? can you provide the steps for the same?

Comment: @VRU A Wubi system is always a dual-boot system. However, you're quite right that actual steps should be provided.

Comment: I had wrote an article on problem of wubi installer & it can be used by you too, go to >> http://techbuzindia.blogspot.in/2013/03/solved-problem-with-wubi-installer.html